# posting a url in the status box in facebook not working

Tags: facebook, sharing

Good Day,

When for some reason we place some links like this one http://www.ricardo.gr/buy/μουσικά-όργανα/πιάνα/midi-keyboards/roland-em-gr1-με-32-ενσωματωμένους-ελληνικούς-ρυθμούς/v/an648462130/ to share in the status bar, facebook does not read the og: information etc....

Once checking in Lint on this URL we see that for some reason it shows a 400 error, in which it cant even open the link. This url does work and we cant for some reason understand why this is happening. Any light would be much appreciated :)

Thanking anyone in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

When I try to access that myself manually it fails:

```
curl -i 'http://www.ricardo.gr/buy/μουσικά-όργανα/πιάνα/midi-keyboards/roland-em-gr1-με-32-ενσωματωμένους-ελληνικούς-ρυθμούς/v/an648462130'
```

I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Wed, 08 Feb 2012 11:02:51 GMT
X-Cnection: close
Content-Length: 324
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerpool_webserver_gr=1125147658.36895.0000; path=/

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Is that URL definitely accessible normally?

Comment: Good day and thank you for your help, yes this link is accessible if you place it in your url it works, what is weird is that some of our articles work and some dont work so i cant figure this one out :) A working link you could check is this one: http://www.ricardo.gr/buy/pc/laptop-αξεσουαρ/lenovo/laptop-ibm-lenovo-προσφορα-λαπτοπ-wifi-1-χρόνο-εγγύηση-175/v/an667656948/

Comment: I get a 400 error on that too (when i copy/paste) - are you sure there aren't characters in that URL that need to be encoded before the request is made?

Comment: for some reason it works for me, but when i encode the url http://www.ricardo.gr/buy/%CE%B7%CE%BB%CE%B5%CE%BA%CF%84%CF%81%CE%BF%CE%BD%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC-%CF%80%CE%B1%CE%B9%CF%87%CE%BD%CE%AF%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1/microsoft-xbox/microsoft-xbox-360/%CF%80%CE%B1%CE%B9%CF%87%CE%BD%CE%AF%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1/sega-superstar-tennis-xbox-360/v/an630928752/ it still does not work...

Comment: have you tried to place the link in your url so you can see the article?